# "command | less" vs "less <(command)"

Tags: bash, pipe, less, file-descriptors, command-substitution

A common "idiom" for viewing large amounts of command output is to pipe it to `less`, via `command | less`. However, it's also possible (perhaps only in `bash`, haven't tested in other shells) to use the `less <(command)` syntax, but `less` tends to complain `/dev/fd/63 is not a regular file`. After poking around in `/proc/*/fd`, I see that in both cases, it's reading from a pipe. The only difference is that in the first case, it's `stdin` being redirected. In the second case, it's getting `/dev/fd/63` as a file name. Does `less` somehow "ignore" the regular file check when reading from `stdin`? Also, how does it determine that `/dev/fd/63` isn't a regular file, even if the contents are text?

Comment: `file <(command)` says: `/dev/fd/63: broken symbolic link to pipe:[10973768]'`

Comment: Command substitution writes to the file `/dev/fd/63` and then pipes this into the command. The problem is, is that this file is not `seekable` meaning it can only be read as a full file without random access. One of the main features of less is that it doesn't read the whole file at once, and so causes this error message.Using a text editor that reads the whole file at once will work. Etc `Vi`

Comment: @Jidder what about piping to `stdin`? Isn't that not seekable as well?

Comment: No i dont think it is seekable, possibly i had misunderstood but i found this `Programs that explicitly check the type of a file before opening it may refuse to work with process substitution, because the "file" resulting from process substitution is not a regular file.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`less` normally refuses to open non regular files like pipes or also binaries. You can use the `-f` operator to force `less` to open non regular files:

```
less -f <(command)
```

Another approach is to use **process substitution**:

```
less < <(command)
```

This causes the pipe that was created with `<()` to act as standard input (`STDIN`) for `less`.

Comment: I believe that you’re a bit confused on the nomenclature. `<(command)` ***is*** process substitution. Changing that to `< <(command)` is just making it complicated.

Answer (score 2):

> `less` tends to complain `/dev/fd/63` is not a regular file

The solution to that, under GNU less at least, is the use of the `-f` option:

```
less -f <(command)
```

Under normal circumstances, `less` will not open non-regular files (stdin excepted, obviously).  This is for your protection.  `-f` forces non-regular files to be opened.